# Cast Applcation in AndroidViewModel constructor parameter

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have a class which extends Application class in my app. I would like to know if there's a way to cast the AndroidViewModel application parameter to MyApp class. Something like this:

```
public class ChartViewModel extends AndroidViewModel<MyApp> {
    public ChartViewModel (@NonNull MyApp application) {
        super(application);
    }
```

With this, I could be able to retrieve MyApp object inside ChartViewModel like this (with no need of casting it every time)

```
MyApp myApp = getApplication();
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Multiple inheritance not allowed . Where as you already have application object inside constructor . Just save it globally.

Comment: Which version of acrhitecture components are you using? you should already be able to do what you want without any casting

Comment: @SamuelEminet oh I`m sorry about that. I do can assign a variable like this, without casting. Thanks for your reply